# Convert a string object with byte characters into a byte object?

Tags: python, unicode

I have a string like this:

```
text = 'b\'"Bill of the  one\\xe2\\x80\\x99s store wanted to go outside.\''
```

That is clearly meant to be byte formatted, however when I look at the object's type, it returns:

```
type(text)  
<class 'str'>
```

I tried encoding at byte and then decoding, but this was the result:

```
text.encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8")
'b\'"Bill of the oneâ\x80\x99s store wanted to go outside.\''
```

How can I get the text properly formatted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As another possible approach, it seems to me that the string you have is the result of calling `repr` on a byte object. You can reverse a `repr` by calling `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = b'test string'
>>> y = repr(x)
>>> y
"b'test string'"
>>> ast.literal_eval(y)
b'test string'
```

Or in your case:

```
>>> x = 'b\'"Bill of the  one\\xe2\\x80\\x99s store wanted to go outside.\''
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(x)
b'"Bill of the  one\xe2\x80\x99s store wanted to go outside.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing both encode and decode on the string object if you do so you will anyhow come to the same state (i.e) string, **just encode that is sufficient**.

```
text = 'b\'"Bill of the  one\\xe2\\x80\\x99s store wanted to go outside.\''
type(text) #This will output <class 'str'>
```

Now, for byte object just make use of below snippet

```
byte_object=text.encode("utf-8")
type(byte_object) #This will output <class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: Right, but now `byte_object == b'b\'"Bill of the  one\\xe2\\x80\\x99s store wanted to go outside.\''`

Comment: ok, I was not clear with the question on seeing @brianpck I can understand your requirement u can make use ast which is meant for this.